# Static Method Call Failure (Java)

Tags: java, android, static

I'm working on someone's Android code that needs to be altered. My aim is to call a static method returning boolean whether the USB device connected to Android phone is the one with right product ID.

The problem is the method I call returns true when a device is connected, while I get a false under one another class. The usage of the method is as follows: USB_VCP.compare0460 should have returned true as it does in another class when I connect the right device, but instead it returns false here in the below code.

I feel like I am missing something here; is that possible the static initializer may cause any problems or is there anything in your mind for why the method returns as I do not expect it to. Above the code, I import USB_VCP class and the code does not fail.

```
public class GlobalVars {

    public static class Holder<T>{
        public T heldValue;
    }

    public static int framenumber;

    private static int wren, rden, read_addr, write_addr;

    public static int WIDTH ;
    public static int HEIGHT;
    public static int COLOR_CHANNELS = 3;

    static {
        if (USB_VCP.compare0460()) // works only if revert this or bring true; but static method normally returns true when 0460 connected{
            WIDTH = 44;HEIGHT = 42;
        }
        if (USB_VCP.compare0835()){
            WIDTH = 84;HEIGHT = 84;
        }
        if (USB_VCP.compare1650()){
            WIDTH = 160;HEIGHT = 120;
        }
        if (USB_VCP.compare1670()){
            WIDTH = 44;HEIGHT = 42;
        } // TO BE CHANGED
    }
```

Comment: I think the problem is your static initializer. Static initializer will execute only once when the class is initiated. Which means when your application starts, the USB_VCP.compare() method will be called only once.

Comment: Then, how can I make it work as I am working with a static method? As far as I scanned online, it is not advised to bring a static method into constructor. How can I make my static comparison method result in changing the global variable?

Answer (score 0):

Use a switch-case block to indicate comparison, instead of using "static" method (which are USB_VCP.compare0460() etc. methods over the code). A direct static method invoke causes calling of initial values when class is first initialized, which is null in my case and returns unexpected values.

Calling static variables picked by switch-case works perfectly.